# To access tuple within tuple values for the value entered by the user in python

Tags: python, tuples

Thanks in Advance! Please suggest the correct code. I used the below code but not able to access the empid entered by the user.

My Query is:

````py
# Create Foll. Information in the Tuple (at least 5 Employees)
# 1. EmpId - Phone Numbers (One Employee can have Multiple Numbers )      
# 2. Accept Empid from User. Display his Numbers only if he exists in the Database(Tuple). Display App. Message if not present```

## My Code
empdetail = (("101",1234587),("102",2588467,2798478),("103",2689822,123456),("104",28398466),("105",8998666))
empid = input("Enter Employee Id :")


for name in empdetail:
    if empid in empdetail:
        res = empdetail[i][i:]
        print(str(res))
        break
    else:
        print("Employee not present.")
        break

print(empdetail)
````

Comment: @EnriqueBet: Please don't change code while you edit. You shouldn't be adding indentations even.

Comment: Ok @Austin, sorry about that! :P

Comment: it seems like the variable `i` doesn't do anything in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
empdetail = (("101",1234587),("102",2588467,2798478),("103",2689822,123456),("104",28398466),("105",8998666))
empid = input("Enter Employee Id :")



for i in range(len(empdetail)):
    if empid in empdetail[i]:
        res = empdetail[i][0:]
        print(str(res))
        break
else:
    print("Employee not present.")

print(empdetail)
```

Comment: If i checked for empid 103 or 104 or 105, it is not giving me correct result. Can you please check

Comment: sorry for that ! I have edited the solution . Please check this now

Answer (score 1):

I would transform that into a dictionary.

```
empdetail = (("101",1234587),("102",2588467,2798478),("103",2689822,123456),("104",28398466),("105",8998666))
empid = input("Enter Employee Id :")


emp_dict =  {key: values for key, *values in empdetail}

if empid in emp_dict.keys():
  print(*emp_dict[empid])

else:
  print("Employee not present.")
```